# how to fix odd date (commandline command) format

Tags: command-line, locale, date

On one server, when i write `date` (or `LC_TIME=sv_SE.utf8 date`) I get:

> ons 18 nov+ 2015 07.45.+53 CET

when I try it on my desktop i get;

> ons 18 nov 2015 07.45.53 CET

Where do the extra "+" comes from?
running `LC_TIME=en_US.utf8 date` don't have extra "+".
What file defines the default output format?
And to what package do it belong?
Hope it can fix it self with just reinstalling the package.

Comment: Have you checked if `date` is aliased to something on the server?

Comment: @kos: `alias | grep date` give no rows, and `/bin/date` gives same problems, so I guess `date` isn't an alias

Comment: Try `type date`, `type` will catch everything, functions, aliases, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug in the locales package, which was [fixed in Ubuntu 13.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/langpack-locales/2.13+git20120306-9).

Comment: thanks, removing the "+" from /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE and running `locale-gen` solved it (servers still running 12.04 LTS, hope to have time to fix that too soon)